# Command line to search all files in all text files in directory recursively

Tags: wordpress, bash, shell, grep

I've just migrated to Octopress. During the migration, the plugin downloaded a lot of unused images from WordPress and now I'm trying to delete it.

I'd like to list all the images and search for all files in `_post` folder and give me all the files that are unused so I can delete them.

I came up with this command.

`find ./ -type f | xargs basename | xargs grep -r {} ../_posts/`

which I don't think it's correct. It gives me this result.

```
grep: Screenshot-2015-07-30-13.04.35.png: No such file or directory
grep: Screenshot-2015-07-30-13.05.41-150x116.png: No such file or directory
grep: Screenshot-2015-07-30-13.05.41.png: No such file or directory
grep: Screenshot-2015-07-30-13.06.33-150x150.png: No such file or directory
grep: Screenshot-2015-07-30-13.06.33-231x300.png: No such file or directory
grep: Screenshot-2015-07-30-13.06.33-518x500.png: No such file or directory
grep: Screenshot-2015-07-30-13.06.33-518x592.png: No such file or directory
grep: Screenshot-2015-07-30-13.06.33.png: No such file or directory
grep: Screenshot-2015-07-30-13.07.47-1024x601.png: No such file or directory
grep: Screenshot-2015-07-30-13.07.47-1120x500.png: No such file or directory
grep: Screenshot-2015-07-30-13.07.47-150x150.png: No such file or directory
grep: Screenshot-2015-07-30-13.07.47-300x176.png: No such file or directory
grep: Screenshot-2015-07-30-13.07.47-786x592.png: No such file or directory
grep: Screenshot-2015-07-30-13.07.47.png: No such file or directory
```

Because even the files that are being used still get listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're not limiting how many lines `xargs` is picking up

```
find ./ -type f | xargs basename | xargs grep -r {} ../_posts/
```

xargs will spawn grep with many strings, you'll get

```
grep -r foo bar baz qux ../_posts/
```

and since grep only wants one pattern, all the rest are assumed to be filenames.

The quick fix is

```
find ./ -type f | xargs -L 1 basename | xargs -L 1 grep -r {} ../_posts/
```

I would rewrite that without xargs at all:

```
find ./ -type f -printf "%f\n" | grep -rFf - ../_posts/
```

This way, you get a single find call, and a single grep call. Should be a lot faster.

---

since `grep -f -` isn't working, the more complicated bash process substitution (see your bash man page)

```
grep -rFf <(find ./ -type f -exec basename '{}' \;) ../_posts/
```

That turns the `find` output into a file that `grep` can read with the `-f` option.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I'm on OSX. So I get this error when running your command above.

find: -printf: unknown primary or operator
grep: -: No such file or directory

Comment: Well, a hybrid then: `find ./ -type f -exec basename '{}' \; | grep -rFf - ../_posts/` -- the recursive grep will be pretty expensive, so you want to limit how many times you call it.

Comment: Not sure why but I get this error `grep: -: No such file or directory`

Comment: Oh, I guess `grep` on OSX does not understand the use of `-` to mean "standard input"